# Using variable inside a for eachrow loop causes error

Tags: julia

I am trying to understand why using variable `i` inside the loop causes an issue

File **main2.jl**:

```
struct MyStruct
    a::Int32
    b::Int32
    c::String
end

df = DataFrame( A=Int[], B=Int[] )
push!(df, [1, 10])
push!(df, [2, 20])
push!(df, [3, 30])

insertcols!(df, 3, :C => MyStruct.(Int32(0), Int32(0), ""))
insertcols!(df, 3, :D => Vector{MyStruct})

println(df)

i = 1
for r in eachrow(df)
    i = i + 1
end
```

I get:

```
julia> include("main2.jl")
|     A |     B |                 D |                    C |
| Int64 | Int64 |          DataType |             MyStruct |
|-------|-------|-------------------|----------------------|
|     1 |    10 | Array{MyStruct,1} | MyStruct(0, 0, \"\") |
|     2 |    20 | Array{MyStruct,1} | MyStruct(0, 0, \"\") |
|     3 |    30 | Array{MyStruct,1} | MyStruct(0, 0, \"\") |
ERROR: LoadError: UndefVarError: i not defined
Stacktrace:
 [1] top-level scope at /usr/home/.../main2.jl:19
 [2] include at ./boot.jl:328 [inlined]
 [3] include_relative(::Module, ::String) at ./loading.jl:1094
 [4] include(::Module, ::String) at ./Base.jl:31
 [5] include(::String) at ./client.jl:431
 [6] top-level scope at REPL[3]:1
in expression starting at /usr/home/.../main2.jl:18

julia>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `i` lives in the global scope and when you write a `for` loop in the global scope, it creates it's own sub-scope. You can solve the issue by changing your `for` loop to

```
i = 1
for r in eachrow(df)
    global i
    i = i + 1
end
```

However, inside function bodies, you do not need to do this (as long as `i` lives in the function body).

This comes down to the fact that in Julia, you often shouldnt be writing non-trivial code out in the global scope. It's considered to be proper form to put code inside functions. If the code isn't inside a function, it won't be compiled and you won't get any of the performance benefits of using Julia. More info about scoping rules can be found here: https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/variables-and-scoping/

There has been a lot of discussion over this issue and what people would rather happens instead. The discussion more or less started here: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/28789 and then a solution was proposed here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/another-possible-solution-to-the-global-scope-debacle/ and then now a new potential solution was discussed here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/new-scope-solution/16707 .

It looks like currently there is no real consensus on how to change the bahaviour and so it will likely stay as is. For what it's worth, I prefer the current behaviour and think it has some advantages, though it is often surprising to newcomers.

Comment: Thanks this fix the issue, I am still wondering anyway why Julia behaves like that, why in this case you are forced to specify that `i` is global. I think I understand the scoping rules now, I just do not understand the advantage of doing this.

Comment: It is indeed extremely surprising to newcomers. Same as having to use @eval to modify a variable from a module even when I have explicitly  exported that variable in that module.

Comment: So I definitively start putting everything into functions. Just moving my whole main code into function main() and then invoking main() at the end fix this issue. This scoping rules are really puzzling, so far the worse I have seen in Julia (I guess they are there for a reason, but they are not intuitive at all).

Comment: Here is a post where Stefan explains the rationale behind the behaviour: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/repl-and-for-loops-scope-behavior-change/13514/9

Comment: Basically, having a compiled language like julia with a global scope and having loops in the global scope act the way you wish turns out to be very complicated and has serious drawbacks.

Comment: Also, you don't have to put your code into a `main()` function, you can just wrap it in a `let` block. The `let` block is equivalent to writing a function with no arguments and then evaluating it, so it looks a bit cleaner.

Comment: I see, this clarifies why scoping works like this. Thanks for the `let` block tip.. I agree it is better for this case (although writting a main function is not a big deal, I have a C background so it does not bother me)